# Op-amp theory vs practice: what have I done wrong

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I'm currently trying to use the MCP6142 op amp in an ultra-low power project (sub-uA ideally). This op-amp has been chosen because it has the highest GBW in the set of the sub-uA op-amp we've reviewed. However in the range of the frequencies we'd like to amplify (3800-4000 Hz) the gain of this op-amp is far from "ideal". See this figure from the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21668d.pdf):

[image]

So we've come up with this circuit to amplify the signal:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBRlRO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Considering the following equations:

```
Vout = G(w)*exp(j * phi(w))*(V+ - V-)
V- = R1 / ( R1 + R2 + 1/(jwC1) ) * Vout
```

We've derived the transfer function `H(w)`:

```
H(w) = G(w) * (1+j*w*(R1+R2)*C1) / (G(w) + j*w.*G(w)*R2*C + exp(-j*phi(w)) + exp(j*(pi/2-phi))*w*(R1+R2)*C);
```

We've used `G(w)` and `phi(w)` plots from the datasheet to compute `H(w)` and plot its curve:

[image]

So we expected a peak gain around 4000 Hz... that we never observed when pluging a waveform generator at the input of the op-amp. Of course, we tried to find the peak by tuning the waveform generator frequency, but we never found it. What could we have done wrong? Have me made a good use of the Gain-Phase plots from the datasheet?

Comment: Sanity check : your expected peak gain is 40dB, at a frequency where the open loop gain is under 30dB according to Fig 2-14. Which raises the question why you expected 40dB.

Comment: Closed-loop gain cannot be higher than open loop gain?

Comment: It can, but that requires positive feedback.

Comment: Do you think we could achieve our goal with positive feedback?

Comment: No, forget the positive feedback as that will not make a reliable circuit. If you're short on gain then better use two opamps, each giving 20 dB of gain.

Comment: No. And attempting it would bring stability problems (oscillation) you really don't want to deal with.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks. Is there a way to use this oscillation phenomena to detect a given frequency (we just want the op-amp to trigger if the frequency is present)?

Comment: You don't want oscillation, it will trigger in the absence of signal too. You might look at an L-C tuned circuit at your frequency of interest.

Comment: I can't understand, why do you need to calculate some transfer functions in purely hypothetical idealistic way? Why not to use the free LTspice tool that will do all "calculations" for you, but with a fairly realistic model of your OPA? If you can't get Microchip model, get something similar from Linear offering, and see all effects right away.

Comment: @AliChen Thanks but so far I haven't managed to use any Spice simulator. Which app would you suggest, for a linux platform? I tried to use Microchip model with Qucs but with no success (nodes were missing)

Comment: LTSpice is free, and runs happily under Wine on Linux.

Comment: I had almost exactly the same issue last week, when designing an 8-pole Butterworth filter in Microcap. Check the amplitude of your sinewave generator. In my case, this was causing the op-amp to saturate, resuting in the strange bode plot behaviour.

Comment: @AliChen why would you use a simulator when you have the real thing to test, which is what the OP has? He's not asking what happens. He already knows that. He's asking why it happens. It's like somebody asks why there's a strange knocking noise from his car engine, and you're saying "have you tried it in Grand Theft Auto?"

Comment: @IanBland, and I did answer exactly why it happens. The dual-axis logarithmic scales are frequently difficult to read and easy to miss the answer by 3 orders of magnitude. Then crafting calculations can miss another order or two easily. The power of **design automation** is exactly to avoid this kind of mishaps. More, what use are the post-factum explanations about insufficient gain at 4kHz, how it better helps to avoids future mistakes than an advice to simulate a circuit first?

Comment: @AliChen No you didn't. By your reasoning we would do no design at all, and just plug random components into LTSpice until we got the apparently correct output, unaware of why we had got that output. Which isn't design at all, it's Edisonian tinkering on a computer.

Comment: @IanBland, Actually, this is not my logic. This is an industry practice of good engineering: (1) Design; (2) Verification/modeling/tapeout; (3) Prototype “A0”; (4) Validation (electrical and functional); (5) Bug fixes; (6) Verification again; (6) Engineering sample “B0”; (7) validation; (8) Production. If you are lucky and exercise exceptional design discipline, "A0" might do into production. But some products might have several (5-6-7) cycles. In the OP case (and your own more dramatic misfortune with exploding 2N2222) the step (2) is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What could we have done wrong? Have me made a good use of the Gain-Phase plots from the datasheet?"

The wrong is that you didn't use the normal engineering practice to model the behavior of your circuit in any SPICE simulator. Linear Technology offers a good LTspice tool free of charge, Texas Instruments does the same (TIna). Microchip has some tools as well. Download the free [LTspice tool](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/#LTspice)  that will do all "calculations" for you, but with a fairly realistic model of your OPA.

If you can't get the particular Microchip model, get something similar from Linear offering, and see all effects right away. The models usually include input parasitic and output limitations. It is advisable to include extra components that would represent parasitics of your PCB and to use more realistic SPICE models for passive components as well.

The LTspice has plenty of ready to go examples, from which it is easy to learn, and modify circuits for your needs.

Answer (score 9):

Reality check - the data sheet shows an open loop gain of about 30 dB at 4 kHz - in numbers, that's a gain of about 31.6. In your derived graph (also at 4 kHz) you are expecting a gain of 100.

Now somewhere you have either your expectations or your math badly wrong.

Comment: And in the circuit diagram you seem to be trying for ~60dB at high frequency if the amp had GBP sufficiently high. Using the GBP limit to provide a lowpass function is not a good idea, if you want a bandpass, design a bandpass, not a HPF with a slow opamp. Further tip, negative feedback is good, you want lots of excess gain it makes all the surrounding stuff more ideal.